# Changing a Button's text inside a ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, button, text

I have a custom ListView set up with custom ArrayAdapter. 
One row is made of 10 buttons. I'm not able to change the buttons caption after clicking the button. Inside the getView method i'm seeting up a holder for all my buttons.
The click listener is in the main activity, it is working correctly (i think so), i'm able to get a reference of the button:

`MyHolder h = (MyHolder) getListView().getAdapter().getView(position, null, null).getTag();


Button b = h.myButton;`

now when i call b.getText(), it gives me the clicked button's text.
But when i try: b.setText("xxx"); the button's text doesnt change.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that calling: `getListView().getAdapter().getView(position, null, null)` manually actually returns the existing View at `position`. This only creates a *new* View with the same data, which is why you don't see any changes and don't receive any errors.

Simply use the View passed in the Button's OnClickListener to change its own text.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    b.setText(...);
}
```

Comment: that's working, Thanks! But my issue is not completly solved. when i press the first button, i need to change the text of the first and second button in my row. How can i get a reference to the other buttons in my row?

Comment: You can use each Button's `setTag()` to save a reference to the matching Button in your adapter's `getView()` _or_ you can use `getParent()` and `getChildAt()` to find the matching Button.